# Error With Array Sorting with BubbleSort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to create an array with 'total' amount of numbers between min and max. And then, sort them using bubble sort. When i execute, i get all zeros. Could someone find what is going wrong? A prompt reply would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class final_project 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int numbers[]; 
        int i, min, max, total; 
        int num;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a minimum random value");
        min = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a maximum random value");
        max = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of random numbers");
        total = scan.nextInt();

        numbers = new int[total];


        i = 0;
        total = 0;
        while ( i < total )
        {
            num = min + (int)(Math.random()*max);;
            numbers[i] = num;  
            total += num; 

            i += 1; /* i = i + 1; */
        }


        bubbleSort(numbers, numbers.length); 
        System.out.println("Your Sorted Array Is: "); 
        for(i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) 
        { 
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " "); 
        } 

    }



    private static void bubbleSort(int[] numbers, int length) 
    { 
        int temp, counter, index; 

        for(counter=0; counter<length-1; counter++) 
        { 
            for(index=0; index<length-1-counter; index++) 
            { 
                if(numbers[index] > numbers[index+1]) 
                { 
                    temp = numbers[index]; 
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index+1]; 
                    numbers[index+1] = temp; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you try printing the unsorted array? Did the result look correct?

Comment: should be `num = min + (int)(Math.random()*(max-min));` and remove `total = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
while ( i < total )
```

to

```
while ( i < numbers.length )
```

Comment: Thank you So much. I don't know why i couldnt catch that simple error. You are a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't execute:

```
        i = 0;
        total = 0;
        while ( i < total )
            ...
```

Also you don't want to increment `total`. Replace your loop with:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        {
             numbers[i] = num;  
        }
```

Comment: Oops, could you help me with how to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a for loop instead of a while loop. A for loop is perfect for iterating through an array.